# load js file to view in ci bonfire

Tags: javascript, php, bonfire

I have a Module call `ftp_data`. Also I have a js file inside my Module Assets folder `bonfire/modules/ftp_data/assets/js/ftp_data.js`.
Now I want to load this file to my view

**Inside View**

```
<!-- Edit by Yesh -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form method="POST" id="url_finder" name="url_finder">
        <div class="span4">
            <h3>Search URL : <input type="search" id="search_url" name="search_url" placeholder="www.example.com"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <button id="url_btn" name="url_btn" class="btn" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- Edit by Yesh -->
```

**inside ftp_data.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('#search_url').keyup(function(){
        var s = new RegExp(this.value.toLowerCase());
        $('.result_table .result_row').each(function() {
            if(s.test(this.innerHTML.toLowerCase())){
                $(this).show();
            }else{
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please vote. If you get something from this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. This is what I found. I hope it will help you too.

```
public function index()
{
//---functions will goes here
//--Add this code before closing public function index
Assets::add_module_js('ftp_data', 'ftp_data.js');
//--ftp_data is the Module name. 
//--ftp_data.js is the name of the js file that is inside the module/assets/js/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To load js/css file in you View module you should use constructor method. You can simply copy my code i have added below.

**code like :**

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        Assets::add_module_js('ftp_data', 'ftp_data.js');
    }
```

**add_module_js()** : first parameter defines the name of the module to be use and second parameter define the files to be load.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on your view file

```
<script src="assets/js/ftp_data.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did this. When I did this, This ftp_data.js file loding before the jquery.min.js file. So, In that case this file not supporting